# Deploying content type from visual studio takes incorrect internal names

Tags: 2013, content-type, visual-studio-2012, elements-xml

I am facing probably the weirdest problem I have ever seen.

We are deploying content types using Visual Studio and here is a sample code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Field ID="{ACF2F646-F52F-48EC-BB7B-17F86324FDDE}" DisplayName="field 1" Name="field_1" Type="Text" />
    <Field ID="{56A6E210-4003-44D0-95C2-9437F9378722}" DisplayName="field 2" Name="field_2" Type="Text" />
    <Field ID="{EDD65584-5713-4508-B05B-519DFD9EA8C7}" DisplayName="field 3" Name="field_3" Type="Text" />
    <!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
    <ContentType ID="0x01006DD2FF8546FD4222A415B76E17157D08" Name="<SOME NAME>" Group="<SOME GROUP>" Description="<SOME DESCRIPTION>" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0" Hidden="TRUE">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{ACF2F646-F52F-48EC-BB7B-17F86324FDDE}" DisplayName="field 1" Name="field_1" />
            <FieldRef ID="{56A6E210-4003-44D0-95C2-9437F9378722}" DisplayName="field 2" Name="field_2" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

When we deploy this content type I get only one field - `field 1`. In the UI I can see one field `field 1` but when I hover the mouse the internal name is set to `field_2` rather than `field_1`. Also `field 2` is not present.

Now if in my content type I add `field 3` reference like below code, I get `field 1` and `field 2` but with internal names of `field_2` and `field_3` respectively. And `field 3` is not present.

```
<FieldRef ID="{EDD65584-5713-4508-B05B-519DFD9EA8C7}" DisplayName="field 3" Name="field_3" />
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Are we missing something over here?

Comment: I have just replicated your code, it works fine, there must be something else that's doing this behavior, take this code and put it in a different solution, it'll work. Check if anything else might be affecting it, any other place that's deploying this content type?

Comment: It worked when I tried on a different site collection. It seems something happened to original site.